# TensorFlow Python script getting killed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a beginner in TensorFlow. My TensorFlow script abruptly exits saying `Killed`. My code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Load data X_train, y_train and X_valid, y_valid

# An image augmentation pipeline
def augment(x):
    x = tf.image.random_brightness(x, max_delta=0.2)
    x = tf.image.random_contrast(x, 0.5, 2)
    return x

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)

def LeNet(x):
    # Define LeNet architecture
    return logits

# Features:
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 32, 32, 3))
# Labels:
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None))
# Dropout probability
prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None))
# Learning rate
rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None))
rate_summary = tf.summary.scalar('learning rate', rate)

logits = LeNet(x)
accuracy_operation = # defined accuracy_operation

accuracy_summary = tf.summary.scalar('validation accuracy', accuracy_operation)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./summary', tf.get_default_graph())

def evaluate(X_data, y_data):
    # Return accuracy with X_data, y_data
    return accuracy

with tf.Session() as sess:

    saver.restore(sess, './lenet')

    for i in range(EPOCHS):
        X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)
        for offset in range(0, len(X_train), BATCH_SIZE):
            end = offset + BATCH_SIZE
            batch_x, batch_y = X_train[offset:end], y_train[offset:end]
            batch_x = sess.run(augment(batch_x))

            # Run the training operation, update learning rate

        validation_accuracy = evaluate(X_valid, y_valid)
        writer.add_summary(sess.run(summary, feed_dict = {x: X_valid, y: y_valid, prob: 1., rate: alpha}))
```

I have omitted the parts which I know for sure are not causing problems. I know which parts are fine because the script was not giving any troubles earlier. After adding certain parts (mainly the **summary writer operations**), the script abruptly says `Killed` and exits after executing a certain number of training operations. I suspect this is due to a memory leak but I can't detect it.

Comment: Can you check the output the the linux `dmesg` command? Was your process killed due to out of memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem just a few days ago. In my case I had some operations that turned out to be computationally very heavy, as I learnt later. As soon as I reduced the size of my tensors, the message disappeared and my code ran. 
I can't tell exactly what is the cause of the issue in your case, but from my experience and from what you say (that error only comes up when adding summary) I would suggest to fiddle with the size of your X_valid, Y_valid. It might just be that the writer can't cope with too much data...